# My iTerm2 prompt is showing my username @ 192 and not my machine name... why?

Tags: linux, macos, iterm2

Why would my iTerm2 command prompt change to `user@192` instead of my machine name? And how do I prevent it from changing to `user@192`?

Comment: What gives `echo "$PS1"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/435966

Answer (score -1):

Its fine to have this behaviour. to test everything is working turn your wifi off than open a new terminal session.
more detailed answer here
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal